# PouchDB data not deleted after destroy

Tags: javascript, couchdb, winjs, indexeddb, pouchdb

In a winJS application, i want to reset the database without restarting the app. I perform a destroy on a pouchdb with following code

```
function destroyPouch() {
    db.destroy(function (err, res) {
        if (res.ok) {
            resetPouch();
        }
    });

 function resetPouch() {
    db = null;
    db = new PouchDB('test-db', { adapter: 'idb', auto_compaction: true });
}
```

When i add new data to the pouchdb, during debug, i see in the properties of db that the _docCount still is the original number of documents stored in the pouchDB.

Also, when adding new data, i get InvalidStateErrors.

Can someone please help me to reset this database without having to shutdown the application?

Thx

Comment: What version of PouchDB? AFAIK destroy is deprecated. (see Docs at http://pouchdb.com/api.html#delete_database)

Comment: PouchDB.destroy() is deprecated, not db.destroy().

Answer (score 0):

`_docCount` is an internal detail. When you do `db.info().then(console.log.bind(console))`, do you still see the old `doc_count`?

Comment: Looks like you're getting an error. Try adding a `.catch(console.log.bind(console))`?

Comment: pouchdb:api test-db +13s info
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: {  },
      outcome: undefined,
      queue: [ ],
      state: [[
    0: "PENDING",
    length: 1 ]
   }

Comment: Sorry, it's just not enough information to go off of. You are providing the debugger output, not the resolution of the promise. I'd recommend turning off debugging and trying again, attaching `.then(console.log.bind(console)).catch(console.log.bind(console))` to everything.

Comment: Ok, sorry it was my bad.
We were accessing the database via a singleton, so when resetting the database, we were still using the old reference. Thank you though for helping!